# How do we write a logic for "facebook like with out open graph" but i need to post the title,description, image

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, fbml

How do we write a logic for "facebook like with out open graph" but i need to post the title,description, image

This situation occured when i am creating the membership sites. I added the like button successfully but the thing when i click the button its getting the data from Home page of my web site. The reason is i gave a url with authorization

So can you help me to creat like button without using OG?

Comment: You need open graph. You can use og:meta tags and use a proxy page to achieve different images, descriptions and URLs within one page.

Answer (score 1):

You can see here

```
http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/tutorial-how-to-add-facebook-share-button-to-your-web-site-pages/
```